# magento 2 append widget

Tags: magento2, frontend, widget, widgets, widget-instance

````
<reference name="content">
    <block type="cms/widget_page_link" name="48fc761f38fa9838fcc3a3b498c47f72" template="cms/widget/link/link_block.phtml">
        <action method="setData">
            <name>anchor_text</name>
            <value>asdfasdfsad</value>
        </action>
        <action method="setData">
            <name>title</name>
            <value>asdfasdfasdfasd</value>
        </action>
        <action method="setData">
            <name>page_id</name>
            <value>2</value>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>```
````

Comment: where you want to add widget ?

Comment: i want to append  button with widget on frontend